# Cursor and keyboard input periodically lags/stutters for 3 hours after startup

Tags: linux, keyboard, linux-mint

When I start up my computer the keyboard input and cursor will lag and jitter once every second for exactly 3 hours. What this means is the cursor will pause for about a few miliseconds while being dragged or clicking on something, and then continue, and the keyboard isn't able to pick up input during that time as well. After the 3 hours are over everything goes back to normal. This has been the case for months and I'm not exactly sure what caused it.

This my system information. I'm using Linux Mint:

```
System:    Host: linux Kernel: 4.15.0-111-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 7.5.0 Desktop: MATE 1.20.1 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa base: Ubuntu 18.04 bionic 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: ASUSTeK product: X551MA v: 1.0 serial: <filter> 
           Mobo: ASUSTeK model: X551MA v: 1.0 serial: <filter> UEFI: American Megatrends v: X551MA.515 date: 04/15/2015 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: N/A condition: N/A model: N/A status: Unknown 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Celeron N2840 bits: 64 type: MCP arch: Silvermont rev: 8 L2 cache: 1024 KiB 
           flags: lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 8663 
           Speed: 536 MHz min/max: 500/2582 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 630 2: 710 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series Graphics & Display vendor: ASUSTeK driver: i915 v: kernel 
           bus ID: 00:02.0 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.19.6 driver: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1366x768~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics (BYT) v: 4.2 Mesa 20.0.8 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Atom Processor Z36xxx/Z37xxx Series High Definition Audio vendor: ASUSTeK driver: snd_hda_intel 
           v: kernel bus ID: 00:1b.0 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k4.15.0-111-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter vendor: AzureWave AW-NE186H driver: ath9k v: kernel 
           port: f000 bus ID: 02:00.0 
           IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
           Device-2: Realtek RTL810xE PCI Express Fast Ethernet vendor: ASUSTeK driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: e000 
           bus ID: 03:00.2 
           IF: enp3s0f2 state: down mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 465.76 GiB used: 466.39 GiB (100.1%) 
           ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Seagate model: ST500LT012-1DG142 size: 465.76 GiB 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 456.96 GiB used: 233.19 GiB (51.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2 
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 2.00 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/dm-0 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 6280.0 C mobo: N/A 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): cpu: 2100 
Info:      Processes: 179 Uptime: 21m Memory: 3.74 GiB used: 1.03 GiB (27.5%) Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 7.5.0 
           clang: 6.0.0-1ubuntu2 Shell: bash v: 4.4.20 inxi: 3.0.27
```

Comment: Can you run `top` to see if there are any processes running during this time, that stop after 3 hours?

Comment: How do I look for the ones that stop after 3 hours? There's a column called `TIME+` that I think says how long a process has been running but that's all I can see that's relevant.

Comment: I don't think you can easily search for "ones that stop after 3 hours", but I would look for anything that has high CPU or RAM usage, and seeing if it disappears after the 3 hours.

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still not able to find the issue. The computer itself isn't slow it's just the keyboard and mouse that lag.